# Resistors corners circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

It is possible to get the corners of a resistor to be like this ?. Im using the circuitikz package and working with Overleaf.

[image]

Comment: Welcom on tex.stackexchange! Please provide a Minimal Working Example for us!

Comment: PostScript related options: [here](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/postscript_1.png)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Ping? I'd like to maintain the `circuitikz` tag with answered questions... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not a standard option, but in a sufficiently recent `circuitikz` is not complex to do — you have to patch an internal command.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@zigzag}{\pgfsetbeveljoin}{\pgfsetmiterjoin}
    {\typeout{Switching to pointy resistors!}}
    {\typeout{Patching resistors failed}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american,thick]
    \draw (0,0) to[R] ++(3,0) to[R=R] ++(3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice however that miter joints can go wild...

```latex
\draw (0,0) to[R] ++(3,0) to[R=R, resistors/zigs=8] ++(3,0);
```

[image]

as you can see, the "pointy ends" are not taken into account in the positioning of labels... (there is a parameter in Ti*k*Z to set a maximum length for miters, you can find it easily in the manual searching for `pgfsetmiterjoin`).

As an aside, you can also say

```
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@zigzag}{\pgfsetbeveljoin}{\pgfsetroundjoin}
    {\typeout{Switching to safe resistors!}}
    {\typeout{Patching resistors failed}}
```

To obtain safe to manipulate (non-puncturing ) resistors:

[image]